# Django rest framework deserialize returns dict

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am running this exact example:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers

But when I get to this part

```
serializer = CommentSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
# True
serializer.object
# <Comment object at 0x10633b2d0>
```

Instead of a 'Comment' object I am getting a 'dict' with the values.
Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Iam using: djangorestframework-2.3.12 and django1.6.1

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're typing `.object` not `.data`?

Comment: absolutely sure: .object

Answer (score 1):

This was actually my bad. I copy-pasted the code and the function 'restore_object' was left outside the CommentSerializer class. The default 'restore_object' deserializes to a dict.

Very sorry